# modx htaccess links are not working

Tags: .htaccess, modx-revolution

Hello MODx developers,

```
I am using MODx revolution. I have just transferred site from one domain to another. as it was a IP based server i have created virtual host with the same name it had previously. 
On previous server the files were located at the root but in new server files are located at tab3, so i have created virtual host that points inside that directory. ie. I have all files in modx/ dir so my virtual host config set to /var/www/modx/
Now the problem is whenever i open home page as well as subdomains (contexts) it works and shows the page but when i open any internal links it says 404 page
```

Ex : if i open www.abc.com => It works
but when i open www.abc.com/contacts => It doesnt works

I see its issue with .htaccess because 
1) if i remove htaccess 
all the subdomains and domains works perfect but inner links like "abc.com/contact" doesnt open up and says 404
2) If i add it again only the main domain and its inner links open...no subdomain or inner links of subdomain works

One more thing....and CLUE is that
when i try to access the same 404 page with ID like this 
www.abc.com/index.php?id=8056

It works

DO i need to add/remove something from htaccess ??

Comment: Got the solution :) there was little miss configuration...thanks for looking in to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the new server running Apache? I had a similar problem where the server was running Zeus & therefore .htaccess didnt work. There is a solution but was too advanced for me. Was easier to install on an Apache server instead.